# How do I substitute a parameter of an XML tag... using Regex?

Tags: regex, autohotkey

Help how do I use regex to replace the value of param below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<games>
    <game id="1001" path="C:\Program Files\Warcraft III\war3.exe" param="" display="1" priority="0"/>
</games>
```

the value of param is empty i wanted to add something to it using regex.
or replace the hole param="" with param="something"

and it has to be the first param after id="1001"
help.

i'm also using autohotkey so.. I don't know if you can just provide me a code to edit xml with autohotkey. :P but regex would do for this.

somebody provided me with this code

```
RegExReplace(xml,"s)id=""1001"".*?param=""\K[^""]+","HELLO WORLD!")
```

it works if the param has a value but it won't work if it doesn't.
how do i make it work.

Comment: You failed to provide the string you want to modify.

Comment: You failed to tag this with the programming language you're using (not all regular expression parsers are equivalent).

Comment: What would happen if param="" is before id="1001"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this, but **you should consider using a proper XML parser instead**, since this regex **will easily fail** in many cases:

```
s/(id="1001" [^>]*param=").*?"/$1something"/
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off looking at an XML/HTML parsing engine here, assuming you are talking about XML/HTML params. Such engines are made for parsing and modifying this kind of content - regexes are not at all ideal for such work.

But it would help to know more about what you are dealing with, too; what's the environment? Is this HTML/XML data? Where are you modifying it? (client? server?) etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the command you posted works as you said, then all you need to do is change the `+` to a `*`, like so:

```
RegExReplace(xml,"s)id=""1001"".*?param=""\K[^""]*","HELLO WORLD!")
```

`+` means "one or more; `*` means "zero or more"